# How do I switch the focus of a current touch down from View A to View B?

Tags: android, kotlin, touch, listener, ontouchlistener

I'm trying to **detect a touch down** on a view which is created after a long-press, and while the user still has their finger down on the screen.

I am currently building a simple app with a pop-up menu which appears when the user executes a long press. This app has an Activity, and a Fragment which appears over the whole screen to display the menu.

The user does a long-press down on the Activity, and this is detected by the activity, which then creates a Fragment, which overlays the whole screen.

The functionality I wish for is the Fragment to then contain code with onTouchListeners which detect this current touch down event (as the user still has their finger on the screen), and assign it directly to views in the Fragment

Here is the code containing the **longClickListener()** which detects the touch in the Activity, and then adds the Fragment.

```
private fun setRootViewLongTouchListener() {
        rootLayout.setOnLongClickListener {
            displayOverlay()
            false
        }
}

private fun displayOverlay() {
        supportFragmentManager
            .beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.rootLayout, OverlayFragment.newInstance(touchXPosition, touchYPosition), "overlayFragment")
            .addToBackStack(null)
            .commit()
}
```

Here is the code inside the Fragment which I'd wish to detect the finger's current touch down (the finger is not lifted between displayOverlay() above being called, and Fragment being created, and the view in the Fragment detecting a touch on it).

```
view.setOnTouchListener { view, motionEvent ->
        if (motionEvent.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN || motionEvent.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
            displayCircleAtTouchPosition(centreCircleOnX(motionEvent.x), centreCircleOnY(motionEvent.y))
        } else if (motionEvent.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            popFragment()
        }
        false
}
```